# JQuery - How to fix mouseover and mouseleave auto loop a lot of times?

Tags: jquery

When I faster to mouseover and leave #go in a short time, it will auto loop a lot of times.
How to fix it??

```
$("#go").mouseover(function(){
  $("#block").animate({ width: "900px" }, 300 );
});

$("#go").mouseleave(function(){                       
  $("#block").animate({ width: "0px" }, 300 );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$("#go").mouseover(function(){
  $("#block").stop(true,true).animate({ width: "900px" }, 300 );
});

$("#go").mouseleave(function(){                       
  $("#block").animate({ width: "0px" }, 300 );
});
```

Comment: No need to do the `true,true`

Comment: I know the stop() can stop the animate but I dont know what is true,true...just finding document

Comment: if you dont use `true` as arguments it will default to `false` which means the current animation queue will not be cleared and animation will complete, so you may face the same problem... the best way is to read the `docs` and experiment your self